# Why my localStorage gets empty each time i reload the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I can't understand what to do. I thought it's just .setItem and .getItem but mayber there is something wrong in the useState change state

```
 const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "products";
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const addProductHandler = (product) => {
    console.log(product);
    setProducts([...products, { id: uuid(), ...product }]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(products));
  }, [products]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveProducts) setProducts(retriveProducts);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Right now you're setting it with your default empty array every time the component mounts. You only want to do that if the key does not exist in localstorage.

Comment: I thought, if there is any change in products then useState for setItems is called. the problem is in useState of getItems then? If you can tell more about it what actually is happening here

Comment: you are setting  `localStorage` as empty array at mount

Comment: I am having similar issue with user (user data after loggin). Maybe anyone can help? I tried moving useEffect but still same.

Comment: The point is that even by changing the order of useEffects (For the set and get localstorage) the problem hasn't been tackled for me, and I needed to deactivate the Strict Mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the component mounts, you set the initial state of `products` to be an empty array. You then store to `localStorage`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(products));
}, [products]);
```

And immediately after you restore the state (the empty array you've just stored) from the local storage, which means that the initial state is always empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const retriveProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
  if (retriveProducts) setProducts(retriveProducts);
}, []);
```

To solve the problem change the order of the `useEffect` blocks (restore and then store), and prevent the storing `useEffect` from setting an empty array to local storage:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const retriveProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
  if (retriveProducts) setProducts(retriveProducts);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(products?.length) { // only store the state if products exists and it's length is greater than 0
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(products));
  }
}, [products]);
```

Comment: ok, so the order also matters while using useEffects? I didn't know about this. your answer worked for my question though. thanks

Comment: Indeed. The order matters. You're welcome :)

Comment: What does ?. means. i couldn't find it and never used it before

Comment: This is the new [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax.

Comment: Thanks Ori Drori

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this. The best explanation so far that solved lots of m problems!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from comment

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "products";
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

const addProductHandler = (product) => {
  console.log(product);
  setProducts([...products, { id: uuid(), ...product }]);
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(products));
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Updating the state on mount if data exists in LC else state would be the default state
  if (localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) {
    const retriveProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveProducts) setProducts(retriveProducts);
  }
}, []);
```